# Oracle substring table based on hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string '1,2,3,4,5,6' and I need output in table format like

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4

1,2,3

1,2

1

Comment: I am aware of connect by level, which outputs all sub-parts as table. But this is not what i need.

Comment: Connect by can be a solution; please post your code and the problem you are having to achieve the needed result

Comment: The thing is, I am not having problem. I just dont know the solution for achieving such output. Selecting string simply from dual table will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query - Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause**:

```
WITH table_name ( list ) AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3,4,5,6' FROM DUAL
),
rsqfc ( list ) AS (
  SELECT list FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR( list, INSTR( list, ',', -1 ) -1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  INSTR( list, ',', -1 ) > 0
)
SELECT * FROM rsqfc;
```

**Query - Hierarchical Query**:

```
WITH table_name ( list ) AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3,4,5,6' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE LEVEL
            WHEN 1 THEN list
            ELSE SUBSTR( list, 1, INSTR( list, ',', -1, LEVEL - 1 ) - 1 )
            END AS list
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY INSTR( list, ',', -1, LEVEL - 1 ) > 0;
```

**Output**:

*(Both output the same)*

```
list
------------
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
1
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not create a new table. Is there any other approach without creating new table.

Comment: @AshutoshAgrawal Just declare the table in a sub-query factoring clause then. I've updated my examples to use this method.